# How To Fix Unsupported Operand Type Error?

Tags: python

I used an alpha beta pruning code but it shows this error

> unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'" in the following line:
>   if (turn+num)%2==1:

This is the code for this section:

```
def main():
num=input('enter player num (1st or 2nd) ')
value=0
global board
for turn in range(0,rows*cols):
    if (turn+num)%2==1: #make the player go first, and make the user player as 'X'
        r,c=[int(x) for x in input('Enter your move ').split(' ')]

        board[r-1,c-1]=1
        printBoard()
        value=checkGameOver(board)
        if value==1:
            print ('U win.Game Over')
            sys.exit()
        print ('\n')
```

What do I do? Please help

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this question is not detailed enough to give you any meaningful help. Please edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example for the issue, including sample input, preferred output, and code for what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

The error says that integer plus string is not defined because plus has different meanings for the string type and the int type. You could change the input line as such

```
num=input('enter player num (1st or 2nd) ') # num is a string
num=int(input('enter player num (1st or 2nd) ')) # num is a int
```